# How do I disable the block marketplace for Editors?

Tags: block-editor

I don't want users with the role of Editor to be able to add block from the WordPress Block marketplace.

How do I disable this capability by editing the theme's functions.php file?

Comment: WP has a block directory, is that what you mean by Marketplace? It's not possible to _buy_ blocks via the block editoor

Answer (score 1):

**The block directory is already disabled for editors.**

In order to use the block directory you must be logged in as a user that can install plugins. This would be administrators on single sites and super admins on multisites.

Unless you have granted this ability to editors, they cannot use the block directory.